# Why does TOML code block formatting look so bad?

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I have a Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54842093) that includes a [TOML](https://toml.io/) code block.

I have tagged the code fence:

````
```toml
````

But the resulting highlighting looks very poor and does not even highlight the comments correctly.

[image]

Given TOML's prevalence in the Python and Rust communities, this surprised me. Is the highlighter for `toml` broken or missing? Am I annotating the code block incorrectly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The shorthand hinting works by looking at the corresponding tag's syntax highlighting ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857)). [toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toml) doesn't have a Code Language (used for syntax highlighting) defined so it was ignored in favour of the tags on the question specifically [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) since it has a specified Code Language `lang-rust`. In the case of multiple tags that have specified Code Languages it "lets highlight.js infer what's the best language to use."

I've [edited the the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54842093/4) to use the explicit `lang-toml` notation:

````
```lang-toml
````

and it now renders as expected (since `lang-toml` is one of the [available languages on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857)):

> ```toml
> [profile.release]
> opt-level = 'z'     # Optimize for size.
> lto = true          # Enable Link Time Optimization
> codegen-units = 1   # Reduce number of codegen units to increase optimizations.
> panic = 'abort'     # Abort on panic
> strip = true        # Strip symbols from binary*
> ```

It may be helpful to have a mod add the Code language for [toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toml) to be `lang-toml` which would fix this issue everywhere it's currently being used and moving forward (any future usage).