# Request to set the TOML tag to default syntax highlighting to lang-ini

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

As per the guidance in [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857)

> If the tag doesn't have a highlighting language specified when it should, create a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on your site's per-site meta to request it.

[toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toml) does not have a language code so it is not being rendered correctly anywhere anywhere

````
```toml
````

or

```
<!-- language: toml -->
```

are currently being used.

`lang-toml` is already in the [list of supported languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857) (the base language of which is `lang-ini` and [should now be available in the syntax highlighting dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378593/1099857) for mods).

---

Related meta question:

1. [Why does TOML code block formatting look so bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416526/15497888)

Examples of posts where toml shorthand hinting is being used, but not being rendered correctly since [toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toml) has no associated language:

- [How do I deserialize an array of objects from TOML to Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70880216/15497888)
- Answer to [How to define test-only dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857478/15497888)
- [TOML decoding in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45169626/15497888)
- [Deserializing TOML into vector of enum with values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48641541/15497888)
- Answer to [Deserializing TOML into vector of enum with values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48651990/15497888)
- [How to deserialize a TOML table containing an array of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60592561/15497888)
- [Using serde to deserialize a HashMap with a Enum key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68579809/15497888)
- [How to make serde deserialize BigInt as u64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60671365/15497888)

Posts where no explicit hinting is being used, but highlight.js may be able to infer the correct markdown if [toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toml) had a set language code:

- [Trouble converting yaml file to toml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69383867/15497888)
- Answer to [Not able to read TOML file using Go with BurntSushi library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43237907/15497888)
- [Parsing a key value pair within a table for TOML file and golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53915596/15497888)
- [(Go) How to use toml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34307488/15497888)

Comment: Color me shocked that an apparently niche language (judging both by the fact that I, arrogantly, had never heard of it, and also by the number of questions on SO with this tag) is an explicitly supported language by our syntax highlighter, while support for dozens of other far more commonly-used languages is MIA.

Comment: What I am far less shocked about is that there is no way for me to actually set the default syntax highlighting language for the [[tag:toml]] tag, as "lang-toml" is simply not an option that appears in the drop-down list. And, before you ask, no, applying some DOM-editing magic doesn't help.

Comment: From the [supported languages list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857) INI and TOML appear in line it seems that `lang-toml` is a supported alias for `lang-ini`. Which is marginally more common at least in number of questions [tag:ini] (which also doesn't have syntax highlighting). Is `lang-ini` an option in the list @CodyGray?

Comment: Haha, no. But that does help explain why it would be supported. INI file formatting is extremely simple (thus almost no code required in the highlighter) and ubiquitous. If TOML uses the INI syntax, then it makes perfect sense it would be supported out-of-the-box. But, yeah, no, `lang-ini` isn't among [the options](https://pastebin.com/hKudvBMq), either, and I can't force it to be one. You did not think it would be easy, did you?

Comment: Ahhh well, it was worth a shot :) Thank you for taking a look. I didn't expect (perhaps naively) that explicitly supported markdown would be not supported in the language code list.

Comment: You thought the two systems would be somehow connected to one another? Heavens, no! Haven't you heard that tight coupling is bad design?!

Comment: I must've been absent that day... and to think all this time I've been under the impression that was _good_ design.

Comment: @CodyGray I wrote up a bug report here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377078/the-code-language-selection-on-the-tag-wiki-page-isnt-in-sync-with-available-an

Comment: Done now; let me know if you see any breakage and need to get this reversed.